# Size of like-button changed on mobile devices

Tags: facebook, size, facebook-like

I've been displaying a like-button on my mobile websites for quite some time now using an iframe. For a few weeks now the size of the button has increased on all mobile devices, but not on for example the iPad or desktop browsers.
Does anyone know why this is happening or what I can do to show the old size, because that fitted perfectly. Now it's too big for it's container.

Thanks in advance,
Cyril

Comment: I too have noticed this behavior, and am having the same issue.  Looks like it's sniffing the user agent and adjusting the style, but can't/doesn't adjust the iframe dimensions, so it gets cut off.

Comment: Seems they have changed it again.. :(

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a bug you should log with Facebook.  Log it at: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs